# How to construct array of pointer of structs in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have problem working with dynamic array of pointer structs. It seemed that at the end of the loop array have only 2 pointers inside. I don't know why is that. I new to C and low level stuff. I am asking for help! Could You please explain me why this is happening? [image]

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Coordinates {
    short x;
    short y;
};

const short BOARD_SIZE = 8;
const short MAX_SIZE = 10;

int main() {


    struct Coordinates **possible_moves = malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(struct Coordinates));

    for (short i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; ++i) {
        struct Coordinates *current_coordinates = malloc(sizeof(struct Coordinates));
        current_coordinates->x = i;
        current_coordinates->y = i;
        possible_moves[i] = current_coordinates;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in this declaration struct Coordinates **possible_moves = malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(struct Coordinates));. You mean sizeof(struct Coordinates *)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the array to be assigned to `possible_moves` is pointers, so allocating size should be one of pointers, not one of the structure.

In other words,

```
    struct Coordinates **possible_moves = malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(struct Coordinates));
```

should be

```
    struct Coordinates **possible_moves = malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(struct Coordinates*));
```

or

```
    struct Coordinates **possible_moves = malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(*possible_moves));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do like this :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Coordinates {
    short x;
    short y;
};

const short BOARD_SIZE = 8;
const short MAX_SIZE = 10;

int main() {
    // struct Coordinates * instead of struct Coordinates **
    struct Coordinates *possible_moves = (Coordinates *)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(struct Coordinates));

    for (short i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; ++i) {
        // struct Coordinates instead of struct Coordinates *
        struct Coordinates current_coordinates = {i, i};
        possible_moves[i] = current_coordinates;
    }
    free(possible_moves);
    return 0;
}
```